# Can't display custom View in Android Studio Layout Editor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-view, android-custom-view

I am struggling to get my Custom View to be displayed in [Android Studio's Layout Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html).

My view is a simple subclass of RecyclerView with custom parameters. I use [`View.isInEditMode()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInEditMode()) to use the given `attrs` only when actually running the app:

```
public class CustomRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    public CustomRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            return;
        }

        final TypedArray styledAttributes = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomRecyclerView, 0, 0);
        /* ... */
}
```

However, previewing a layout containing this View results in an empty Preview pane (not even the phone's frame):

[image: preview with custom view]

If I replace my View by a RecyclerView, the Preview works as expected:

[image: preview with default view]

I don't see what I should do here: if the RecyclerView is correctly displayed and all I do in my subclass's constructor is call `super()` and return if `isInEditMode` is true, then what could explain my View not being displayed?

### What can I do to get my custom View displayed in Android Studio's Layout Editor?

Comment: did you try rebuilding your project?

Comment: I tried several times **Rebuild** and **Invalidate Caches and Restart**, but the problem persists.

Comment: Do you use isInEditMode? Do you have some exception in LayoutEditor?

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin: Yes I do use isInEditMode, as I explained before the code sample, showed in the code sample and mentioned again after the illustrations. I don't have any exception in LayoutEditor.

Comment: As for me, when I used isInEditMode, I have similar problem, when I removed it, all became visible.

Comment: Actually reopening this project with an up to date Android Studio did successfully show the UI in the Preview pane, so I can only guess this was a bug in the IDE and has been fixed since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, opening the same project with Android Studio **2.1.2** does successfully display the UI in the Preview Pane. I can only guess this was a bug in the IDE and has been fixed since I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem use lower

> API levels like 26

then rebuild the project.

Comment: Could you give more context on your answer pls